# Get Origin Repo's Master as a branch of my fork in Git

Tags: git, github

I'm familiar with the basics of git, but not the advanced stuff, and I'm a bit lost here. While I do my checkouts and commits and clones on the command line, I honestly use the Github UI for forking and merging with other repos.

So my problem is this: A while back I cloned a repo, let's call it `Upstream`, and made some changes. Let's call my fork `Downstream.` I submitted my code as a pull request, but `Upstream` didn't want my changes. Oh well, now I maintain `Downstream` for myself and a few other users who want the functionality I added. Every now and then I pull down the changes from `Upstream/master` into `Donwstream/master`.

Now, I'd like to do some more work on `Upstream`, and once again submit my changes as a pull request to them. However, my `master` has changes they've already said they don't want, so I want to re-fork their `master` into a new branch on `Downstream` (ie, `Downstream/upstream-master`). How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If your repository doesn't currently have the upstream remote, `git remote add upstream https://github.com/Foo/Bar.git` and then `git fetch upstream`.
2. Get the code from upstream: `git checkout upstream/master`
3. Make a new local branch that points to the code you just checkout out: `git checkout -b upstream-master`
4. [Optional] Cherry pick your work from your old branch onto the one you just made. `git cherry-pick abc123`

I left these as separate commands for simplicity, but there is probably a way to combine them into a single command.

Comment: The first two can be combined as `git checkout -b upstream-master upstream/master`.

Comment: Thanks. For anyone that comes across this in the future, before doing the above, you need to do the following: `git remote add upstream https://github.com/Foo/Bar.git` then `git fetch upstream`

@mkasberg, can you add that to your answer?  :)

Comment: Added as the first step.